# removeAttr working in FF but not in IE

Tags: jquery

I want to disable all "a" tags from a dynamically (using JavaScript) created table using jQuery.

I tried

```
$("tableId a").removeAttr("href");
$("tableId a").removeAttr("onclick");
```

This is working in FF but not in IE

Comment: [Its working](http://jsfiddle.net/fShBv/)

Comment: its not working for dynamically created table.

Comment: try `$("#tableId a").removeAttr("href");`

Answer (score 1):

Try neutralizing the links with a loop:

```
$("tableId a").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', '#');
  $(this).attr('onclick', 'javascript:void(0);');
});
```

Comment: no. I tried it. its working in FF only. COuld this be an issue as the table is dynamically created using java script?

Comment: How about this: `$('tableId a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: i just tried to bind an alert on earch click in above loop. But that didnt work either.

Comment: Can you post the code which generates the table? That might be the problem.

Comment: var str1="<tr><td><a href='#' onClick='someEvent()'"+name+"</a></td></tr>";$("#tableId tbody:last").append(str1);

Comment: Is that *really* it? That is completely invalid HTML, which might be why your script isn't working in IE. `onClick` should be `onclick` and the `<a>` tag should be closed. Here's some documentation: http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/a/

Answer (score 1):

Use prop. removeAttr doesn't work for inline onclick events on IE 6,7 and 8.

```
$("tableId a").prop("onclick", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support `table` id's, but you can embed the `table` inside a `div`:

```
<div id=...>
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```